# How to migrate db from SQL server to SQL Azure which contains asp.net membership provider with data

Tags: azure, asp.net-membership, azure-sql-database

In one of my project i have used Asp.net membership provider and there is some data on production environment.Now i need to to migrate that DB with SQL Azure.

I have used [SQLAzureMW](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) tool to migrate that and that tool has done proper migration except **aspnet_user** table's data and some of **SPs** and i have skip that table manually at time of final step on that tool

When i have looked in to data then aspnet_users table's data missing!

I have also read about [New script for SQL Azure](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2006191) but i think that is for to create from scratch, i also heard about [Universal Provider](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) but confused in that.

As per my requirement what steps i need to follow to migrate existing sql db to windows azure sql db(WASD) with data and considering this what would be impact of that on application?

*Note:* Session State is also being managed using SQL provider here

**Update**

**Again i have tried it with SQLAzureMW tool and this time i noticed that due to default collation type some of Sps were missing so i have run that manually as per [this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/11/sql-server-cannot-resolve-collation-conflict-for-equal-to-operation/)**

**However still i need to make sure would there be any issue regarding session state Or other thing as i have migrate it's from existing db to WASD?**

Answer (score 0):

the SQLAzureMW tool show any message that you skip? 
I have had many problems with this tool, but finally I could did everything with it. I would try creating first time Data Schema Only, and after copying the Data. Maybe you should use also DROP and CREATE option when generating the script, if the old data can't be overwrite. I hope this helps!